# Is there a provision in C to find the structure type from its pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

If we have two types of structure say apple and orange with their instances as a1 and o1, then we have a pointer to of type void then is there a way of knowing what type of structure it points to?...

Comment: No. Not at runtime.

Comment: Derive Apple from a pointer to a fruit? I already read this question some days ago ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not without a great deal of hacking. If you have control of the source code, you could conceivably place this information into the structures:

```
typedef enum {
    STRUCT_TYPE_APPLE,
    STRUCT_TYPE_ORANGE
} _struct_type;

typedef struct {
    _struct_type type;

   /* Your "apple" data */
} apple;

typedef struct {
    _struct_type type;

   /* Your "orange" data */
} orange;
```

You can then cast to an appropriate type during debugging and check the value of `type`. Naturally, this is riddled with brittleness. Notably, if you aren't sure what type of structure you're going to be getting, casting and checking `type` could well get you something with the same value of `STRUCT_TYPE_APPLE` or `STRUCT_TYPE_ORANGE`.

Comment: This is what the linux kernel does in several places. They also typically use a "ancestor" struct (see e.g. `struct sockaddr` as a generic form of sockaddr_in and sockaddr_in6) so the size of the struct is large enough. I have to agree with kfb about the brittleness though...

Answer (score 5):

C does not maintain this sort of information at runtime. So you're out of luck, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do this natively in C.

One solution would be to stub `malloc()` for the types you're interested in and maintain a table of pointers as keys and object types as values. Read that table when you need to know the type.

Don't forget to make similar stubs for `calloc()` and `free()`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to check the type of a structure is to use magic values.

```
struct <your_struct> {
   uint32 magic;
   // rest of your struct
}
```

You could then check if the magic values match during runtime with something like

`assert(<your_struct>->magic == STRUCT_MAGIC_CONSTANT);`